# Execute program and enter 'string[] args' through windows command prompt

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I heard somewhere that it is possible to execute program and enter 'string[] args' of main function by cmd in Linux[image]

Is it possible to do the same in Windows? Can I execute program and add this arguments to main function by Windows cmd?
I want to do something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just add the arguments as you would to any other program. Separation characters or quotes are not necessary, unless you need to pass an argument that contains spaces by itself. You don't normally need to use the `start` command to launch an application either. So your command line will just be

```
myprogram arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: It looks like it is working but not with my program. Can you maybe help me with that too? I tried your solution by opening my browser in this way and it work but when I tried to open my application Im getting "System Windows can not find this file"

Comment: @SEGMK Then you're probably not in the right location. You need to use `cd` to change to the path where your application resides. You can find the path in the output of the compiler.